# Skip Dublicate Integers

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a program that would ask the person to write 10 integers, the program should print out the integers that has not already been written, meaning it skips the duplicate integers.  I know that I'm supposed to have another for loop but how am I supposed to write it?

If I would write `"10, 5, 6, 5, 9, 5"` it would print out `"10, 5, 6, 9"`

This is my current code.

```
int main()
{
    const int target = 10;
    int num[target];
    cout << "Write " << target << " integers by space: ";

    for (size_t i = 0; i < target; i++)
    {
        cin >> num[i];
        cout << "[" << num[i] << "]"
             << " ";
    }
};
```

The output is the same as the input. It never skips the same duplicate.

Some people tell me to use a nested for loop and have something like this, but I don't know how to implement it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++) {
    if (i > 0 && num[i - 1] == num[i]);

    cout << num [I] << " "; 
}
```

Comment: Please show the output of your code as well.

Comment: Of course it doesn't skip the same integers, you never tell it to. [std::unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) would be a good choice.

Comment: Nope, a `std::vector<int>` would also work and maintain the order. (you just have to write the checks)

Comment: Some people say create a for loop with num[i] - 1. something like this 

"for (int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++) {
    if (i > 0 && num[i - 1] == num[i]);

    cout << num [I] << " "; 
}" But I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: *Some people say create a for loop*  -- And others here say to use `unordered_set`.  Then it doesn't matter how many numbers are entered.

Comment: I'm not that experienced yet to even know what set is in c++. Keep it basic please,

Comment: *I'm not that experienced yet to even know what set is in c++* -- Isn't this a good time to learn what it is?  As to "keep it basic", that is a matter of opinion as to what is "basic".  Since you didn't mention what you can or cannot use in the question, the assumption is to use whatever works efficiently and easily.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do it is use both a [std::unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find) and a [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). The unordered_set can be used as the logic for determining whether the input is unique. If it is just add it to your vector.

A short example (with minimal input error handling) would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

int main (void) {
    
    std::vector<int> vi{};                      /* vector of int to preserve order */
    std::unordered_set<int> us{};               /* set for ensuring only unique ints */
    int i = 0, n = 5;
    
    std::cout << "enter " << n << " integers\n";
    
    while (i < n) {
        int tmp;
        std::cout << "  " << i+1 << ") ";       /* prompt for input */
        if (std::cin >> tmp) {                  /* validate EVERY input */
            if (us.find(tmp) == us.end()) {     /* if tmp not in set */
                us.insert(tmp);                 /* insert tmp in set */
                vi.push_back(tmp);              /* insert tmp in vector */
            }
            i++;                                /* only increment on good input */
        }
        else {  /* handle error */
            std::cerr << "  error: invalid\n";  /* display error */
            std::cin.clear();                   /* clear stream state */
            /* clear all characters to end of line */
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }
    
    std::cout << "\nunique integers\n";
    for (const auto& v : vi)
        std::cout << " " << v;
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/vector_unique_int
enter 5 integers
  1) 2
  2) bananas
  error: invalid
  2) 4
  3) 5
  4) 2
  5) 4

unique integers
 2 4 5
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: I'd suggest moving the `i++;` that's only supposed to occur on good input inside the `if(std::cin >> tmp) { ... }` block instead of a `continue` statement in the error-handling block.

Comment: Yep, that makes sense as well and brings it within the good input block.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by using bool. I still don't know how I would write it in another way, please if there is provide me with another solution.

```
int main()
{
    const int target = 10;
    int num[target];

    cout << "Write " << target << " integers by space: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < target; i++)
    {
        cin >> num[i];
        bool unique = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            if (num[j] == num[i])
            {
                unique = false;
                break;
            }
        if (unique)
            cout << "[" << num[i] << "]"
                 << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output Was :

```
Write 10 integers by space: 10 5 10 3 2 5 1 10 9

[10] [5] [3] [2] [1] [9]
```